# Getting Essbase studio, Drill through error:"Null DTExecuteReportOut object returned from provider"

Tags: hyperion, essbase, drillthrough

I am getting "Null DTExecuteReportOut object returned from provider" while running Drill through report created from Essbase Studio(11.1.2.3).

The report works fine for lower levels but gives this error when trying to pull at higher level like generation 2. In the report, under Advanced Setting I have Acct and Org set at Gen 2 and time and scenario at level 0. All the 
 hierarchies are recursive.

Also, the users demand to have row governor at 60000 rows. I have changed the server.properties file for it.

Still keep getting this error.Can anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Check your logs in:

> /u01/EPM/Oracle/Middleware/user_projects/domains/EPMSystem/servers/AnalyticProviderServices0/logs/apsserver.log

You'll see a java exception in there. Basically what's happening is the drill you are running runs an MDX query to build a list of LEAVES that gets passed to your template SQL. When you drill at a level that brings back too many leaves, you get this error (we are on 11.1.2.4.002).

I just spoke with Oracle and they told me the only way to resolve this is to apply patches to Essbase Studio. Here are the patches they are having me apply:

```
=== Essbase === 

Latest patches 

Essbase 
27397226 PATCHSET UPDATE: HYPERION ESSBASE SERVER 11.1.2.4.023 (Patch) 
27397214 PATCHSET UPDATE: HYPERION ESSBASE RTC 11.1.2.4.023 (Patch) 
If needed: 
27397220 PATCHSET UPDATE: HYPERION ESSBASE CLIENT 11.1.2.4.023 (Patch) LINUX 
27397211 PATCHSET UPDATE: HYPERION ESSBASE CLIENT MSI 11.1.2.4.023 (Patch) WINDOWS 

Analytic Provider Services - APS 
27397232 PATCHSET UPDATE: HYPERION ANALYTIC PROVIDER SERVICES 11.1.2.4.023 (Patch) 

Essbase Studio 
25225889 PATCHSET UPDATE: ORACLE ESSBASE STUDIO SERVER 11.1.2.4.016 (Patch) 
25225885 PATCHSET UPDATE: ORACLE ESSBASE STUDIO CONSOLE MSI 11.1.2.4.016 (Patch)
```

**Note:** After applying the patch and starting the Essbase Studio Server, remember to run the `reinit` command from the Essbase Studio Command line. This will upgrade the Essbase Studio catalog to be the same version as the server. Also be sure to use the matching Essbase Studio Console version.

Make sure you test this in a QA/DEV environment as the patches may have performance issues associated with them.